# jquery namespace: how to pass default options from one method to the subsequence methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

How can I pass the **default options** from one method to the **subsequence methods**?

For instance, I have some **default setting** in the `init` method. and I want to use these settings for other methods such as `show`,

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                element:    "selection"
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            alert(o.element);
        },
        show: function(o) {
            alert(o.element);
        },
        hide: function() {
            alert(o.element);
        }
    };

 $.fn.plugin = function( method ) {

    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

var blah = $('#hello').plugin('show'); // TypeError: o is undefined
```

I would want to get `selection` as the answer... is it possible?

**EDIT:**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.plugin = function( method ) {

        if ( methods[method] ) {
          return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
          return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
          $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }    

     }; 

     $.fn.plugin.defaults = {
        attr: 'checked',
        expected: true,
        onChange: function(){}
      }; 

    var methods = {

        init: function(options) {
            var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $this = this;

            $this.show();
            //alert(o.attr);
        },
        show: function(options) {

            var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            alert(o.expected);
        },
        hide: function(object) {
            alert(o.element);
        }
    };


})( jQuery );
```

[reference](http://ryanflorence.com/use-your-fn-jquery-namespace/)

```
var blah = $('#hello').plugin('show',{expected:"#hello world"});
```

now I get `#hello world` (correct)

but,

```
var blah = $('#hello').plugin('init'); // returns nothing
```

I would want to get `true` as the answer because `init` is accessing `show`. So how do I access **other methods** from **a method**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you are trying to reinvent extensible jquery plugins (aka jQuery UI Widgets).  I can walk you though a lot of how to accomplish what you are trying to do, but it really is reinventing the wheel.  The jQuery UI Widget Factory is great for this type of thing.

[jQuery Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) -- This is their old documenation, but it outlines the widget factory better than anything else, IMHO.  They have made some minor changes to it in 1.9/1.10, but most of the concepts are still the same.

**Edit**

Here's my modifications to your code.  I believe this does what you were looking for.

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                element:    "selection"
            }

            this.options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            alert("init: " + this.options.element);
        },
        show: function() {
            alert("show: "  + this.options.element);
        },
        hide: function() {
            alert("hide: " + this.options.element);
        }
    };

 $.fn.plugin = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    } 
    return this; // this is needed to ensure chainability
 };

})( jQuery );

var blah = $('#hello').plugin('init').plugin('show');​
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am not making any widget. I am just trying to learn using namespace in a plugin but it seems that namespace is very difficult if I want to have some basic default settings to be shared among the methods. Another trouble is - how do I call a method in another method? If I just stick to basic plugin then I have no such issues...

Comment: Don't let the term `widget` fool you.  A widget is merely a plugin, exactly like what you were building.  But the widget factory has extensibility built into it -- solving a lot of the problems you are going to face.  If you want me to show you how to get your code to work, I can do that, but if you are really interested in plugin authoring I would highly recommend widgets.  I can help you with either / both -- just let me know which direction you are interested in heading.

Comment: thank you so much Jason. I would love to know better in plugin authoring before going for `widget` as I want to learn it step by step... I have done an edit in my question - I seem have managed to pass `options` among methods but ugly. Then my final problem is - how to access other methods from a method. thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your edit Jason. Would you mind have a look at my edit? Thank you.

Comment: Your edits look pretty good.  Missing the part about chainability, which most plugin consumers expect plugins to do.

Comment: thank you Jason. how `widget` would solve problems I am facing? I just read an article - it says `namespaces` are old school... http://blog.millermedeiros.com/namespaces-are-old-school/ how come!??

Comment: Javascript doesn't really support namespaces.  Different developers have engineered different ways to mimic them -- some to greater success than others.  And of course everyone has their own opinion of the various methods.  I created a simple widget if you would like to look through the basics of using the jQuery UI Widget Factory -- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nREYh/2/)

Comment: `Javascript doesn't really support namespaces` then it now makes sense! thank you. Thanks for the JSFiddle as well! Can I ask - ` _create`, `_setOption`, & `_destroy` are these functions that we have to follow when making a `widget` or are they just custom functions?

Comment: Those are part of the widget factory.  I created a FAQ to stackoverflow about creating a widget using the factory.  If it gets published I'll send you the link.