# How to access the sub method inside a method from a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, jquery-1.9

How can I access the sub method inside a method from a plugin? For instance, in the `init` method, I want to access the `page` method inside `manage`,

```
$this.cms(manage.page); // ReferenceError: manage is not defined
```

the basic structure,

```
(function($){

    var methods = {

        defaults: function(options) {

            // Default options.
            var defaults = {
                setup: {
                    directory: ""
                }           
            }

            // Always leave this line here.
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            // Return the processed options.
            return options;

        },

        init : function( options ) {

            // Must declare a this as the plugin's root itself.
            var $this = this;

            // Call the local method from the plugin itself to get the processed options.
            var o = $this.cms('defaults',options);
            //alert("nothing to load");


            $this.cms(manage.page);
        },

        manage : {

            page: function(options){

                // Must declare a this as the plugin's root itself.
                var $this = this;

                // Call the local method from the plugin itself to get the processed options.
                var o = $this.cms('defaults',options);

                alert("page method");

            },
            menu: function(options){
            }

        },

        add : function( options ) {

        },

        erase : function( options ) { 

        },

        remove: function(object,options) { // to be developed.

        }
    };

    $.fn.cms = function( method ) {

        // @reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.cms' );
        }

        return this; // this is needed to ensure chainability @reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008121/jquery-namespace-how-to-pass-default-options-from-one-method-to-the-subsequence

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Is it possible or any other better way of doing it? I just want to have children methods inside the parent methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `manage.page` with the code you have. It only allows you to invoke properties of `methods`, not further properties.

You could put `page()` on the `manage` object and pass "page" to the plugin's function.

Comment: Thanks. How do I put `page()` on `manage` object? Can you show me some examples please...?

Comment: @lauthiamkok That's a basic JavaScript question. I recommend researching how objects work in JavaScript. You could make the `manage` property a function that returns that new interface, of which you then call methods (you'll be outside of the *jQuery chain* though if you do that).

Comment: @roasted Sure could, but then you need to design an interface to invoke that via a string (currently, it only supports direct members on `methods`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am doing it right or not, but here is my solution...

```
(function($){

    var methods = {

        defaults: function(options) {

            // Default options.
            var defaults = {
                setup: {
                    directory: ""
                }           
            }

            // Always leave this line here.
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            // Return the processed options.
            return options;

        },

        init : function( options ) {

            // Must declare a this as the plugin's root itself.
            var $this = this;

            // Call the local method from the plugin itself to get the processed options.
            var o = $this.cms('defaults',options);
            //alert("nothing to load");


            $this.cms("manage").page();
        },

       manage : function(options){

            // Must declare a this as the plugin's root itself.
            var $this = this;

            // Call the local method from the plugin itself to get the processed options.
            var o = $this.cms('defaults',options);

            // Set the list for holding properties.
            var properties = {
                page : function(){ $.fn.page(); }
            }

            // Return the property.
            return properties;

        },

        add : function( options ) {

        },

        erase : function( options ) { 

        },

        remove: function(object,options) { // to be developed.

        }
    };

    $.fn.cms = function( method ) {

        // @reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.cms' );
        }

        return this; // this is needed to ensure chainability @reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008121/jquery-namespace-how-to-pass-default-options-from-one-method-to-the-subsequence

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then another plugin for `page`,

```
// A namepace structure:
(function($){

    var methods = {

        defaults: function(options) {

            // Default options.
            var defaults = {
                setup: {
                    directory: ""
                }           
            }

            // Always leave this line here.
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            // Return the processed options.
            return options;

        },

        init : function( options ) {

            // Must declare a this as the plugin's root itself.
            var $this = this;

            // Call the local method from the plugin itself to get the processed options.
            var o = $this.page('defaults',options);

            alert("a page plugin: list page");
        },

        remove: function(object,options) { // to be developed.

        }
    };

    $.fn.page = function( method ) {

        // @reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.page' );
        }

        return this; // this is needed to ensure chainability @reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008121/jquery-namespace-how-to-pass-default-options-from-one-method-to-the-subsequence

    };

})(jQuery);
```

It seems long/ tedious, but works.